# MAC changer and VPN can be trusted?

Tags: vpn, ip-spoofing, mac-address, ip, mac-spoofing

I must spoof my identity for some reason.
Are Technitium Mac Address Changer App on windows and VPN is a trusted way to be anonymous?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: can you explain why ?(for my info... )

Comment: if i use public network , such as a public place and MAC address changer , am i safe ?

Comment: Safe from what? Who's following you? Your browser has an almost-unique fingerprint, your VPN provider could give up information on you to the authorities, you could make a mistake. There are tens of angles for this. There's no way to give an extended answer to your question, unless you make it better and more specific.

Comment: In fact , I want to be free from government control on the Internet ....
tor is a good choose ?

Comment: Tor is one of the many tools. a MAC changer is not. The MAC address (when used at home) does **not** propagate to the Internet. It is used on the **local** network only.

Comment: I don't want to anyone logs my MAC Address....
not for passing filtering...